# VBA to change the format of date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column `V` which contains date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. However, system format shows it as `mm/dd/yyyy`. I want to convert the date format from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `dd-mmm-yyyy`.

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("W" & i).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"`

When I convert it using the above code, it changes the value from `08/02/2017` to `02-Aug-2017`. It should change to `08-Feb-2017`. Please assist.

Comment: I don't believe that. There has to be a mistake with the date in the cell. It only does what is there... Maybe you should just enter the date in the cell again and retry it...

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me... You have the wrong date in the cell if it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Check your regional settings.  Excel thinks you're entering 2nd August - I have this same problem when reports are set up in a hurry on a couple of our systems and the user leaves it with an American date .... starting to feel a rant coming on about people not ticking the right box.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the very beginning and try to simplify everything. 8.Feb.2017 is the 42774th day in the Excel system. Thus, in an empty sheet run the following and check the results:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    [a1] = 42774 '08-Feb-17
    [a2] = [a1]
    [a3] = [a1]
    [a4] = [a1]

    [a2].NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
    [a3].NumberFormat = "mmm-dd-yyyy"
    [a4].NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"

End Sub
```

---

In Excel, day 1 is 1-Jan-1900.
In VBA day 1 is 31-Dec-1899.

Comment: Actually, day 1 is 1 Jan 1900.  And day 0 is displayed as 0 Jan 1900.  And day 60 is displayed as the non-existent 29 Feb 1900.  Silly Excel.

Comment: @YowE3K - true, I was thinking about VBA.

Comment: Ahh - I hadn't realised that it worked backward in VBA and therefore treated day 60 as 28 Feb 1900 and therefore day 0 as 30 Dec 1899.  I thought they both did the same thing.  (Today's piece of trivia that I have learned :) )

Comment: @YowE3K - yup, this is to fix a bit the 1904 problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You have entered "08/02/2017" - This is interpreted as input in the format of "mm/dd/yyyy". As a result, the cell is showing "02-Aug-2017".

You must change your system date format to read the input (08/02/2017) as date value with format "dd/mm/yyyy". After that your cell will show you the date in desired format & value (08-Feb-2017).

To change the system date format, go to Control Panel > Region & Language. Your current format must be "English (United States)" [or something with mm/dd/yyyy date format]. Change it to "English (United Kingdom)".

This should take care of your problem.